# Number of Museums' visitors and ticket revenue

Tags: data-request, historical, europe, glam

I am looking for details about Museums' visitors and revenue from tickets, in specific European Museums.

I made a simple Google research and couldn't find something useful. Only a couple of pages where other people were looking the same data as me.

Ideally, I would love to have in addition a dataset of reviews for each of the museums. For example, tripadvisor reviews.

Are you aware any dataset like this or any way that I could construct it myself?

Comment: You mean income of visitors, or income of museums?

Comment: Income of museums from tickets.

Answer (score 3):

**For EU museums**: have you seen http://www.egmus.eu/nc/en/statistics/complete_data/ ? Seems to have what you want *except* aggregated by country

---

*This isn't exactly what you're looking for but I wanted to provide you this lead in case it helps for comparisons to the US and hopefully it will help people who land here later.*

**For US museums**:

Take a look at IMLS' (Institute of Museum and Library Services) datasets at `data.imls.gov`, including this one:

- Interactive dataset: https://data.imls.gov/Museum/Museum-Universe-Data-File-FY-2015-Q1/bqh6-bapa
- Data dictionary: https://www.imls.gov/assets/1/AssetManager/MUDF_Documentation_2015q1.pdf
- API: https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/#/data.imls.gov/kitj-k8bg
- Relevant columns:

  - INCOME - Total revenue from most recent Internal Revenue Service (IRS) 990 Form
  - DISCIPL – Museum discipline code of organization (*aka type of museum*)

If you are by any chance interested in libraries too, https://data.imls.gov/browse?category=Research+%28Statistical%29 has a lot of interesting information on libraries such as collection sizes and revenues.

Comment: I wish we had something similar in Europe

Comment: @Tasos - have you seen http://www.egmus.eu/nc/en/statistics/complete_data/ ? aggregated by country but better than nothing I think?

Comment: I want to examine specific exhibits on several museums in eu countries and then combining the results with more general stats. This one could certainly help me on the second part. Thank you :)